# Using freeglut without an IDE

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I tried to use freeglut with codeblocks and also Microsoft visual studio 2010. I tried the [official codeblocks instruction page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_FreeGlut_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks)
but still I couldn't successfully use it. So I tried directly including the freeglut file like 
this(by copying it in the folder of my c++ files):

```
#include "freeglut.h"
```

And then I tried to compile with gcc compiler through the terminal. It threw a ton of different errors. How can I use freeglut without an IDE? If I can't do you have any suggetions/links as to how I can install and use?

**Note** Using windows 7 32 bit

Comment: install linux distro (I recommend Arch Linux), install freeglut, compile.

Comment: writing some of the error can help us to understand...

Comment: Also the command you issued to the terminal might be helpful.

Comment: the first error said
undefined reference to '_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'

Comment: I saved all the freeglut related files in a particular folder and then I directed to the folder and typed 
g++ -o try1 tester.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not telling gcc that your program has to link with freeglut.lib. Compile your program with flag `-lglut`

You need to use this information for [setting up freeglut on cygwin](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/161519-Installing-GLUT-with-Cygwin)

Comment: as in g++ -lglut try1 tester.cpp ? 
and what folders or files do I need to have copied to the folder of my C++ file

Comment: yes! you no need to copy anything as long as libraries are their in system path.

Comment: Sorry that i missed that you are on windows. you using gcc through cygwin ?

Comment: Update my answer with required details :)